# Haskell - zipping a list with a list of lists elementwise

Tags: haskell

I have a list `l1`:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

and a list of lists `l2`:

```
l2 = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

And I'm trying to zip the first element of `l1` with the first list of `l2` and second element from `l1` with the second list from `l2` etc, what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
l3 = [[(1, a), (1, b), (1, c)], [(2, d), (2, e), (2, f)], [(3, g), (3, h), (3, i)]]
```

How can I do this? I know it has to be some combination of map and zip. Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by writing a function that pairs one element with a list,

```
f :: a -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
f x ys = ...
```

so that `f 1 [a, b, c] == [(1, a), (1, b), (1, c)]`.

You can do this with explicit recursion or by using [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:map).

Then write another function that calls this function for each pair in `l1` and `l2`.

```
g :: [a] -> [[b]] -> [[(a, b)]]
g xs yss = ... f x ys ...
```

so that `g l1 l2 == l3` according to your definitions of `l1`, `l2` and `l3`.

You can do this with explicit recursion or by using [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith).

Comment: It can eventually be shortened into `zipWith (map . (,))`.

Comment: In the function that pairs one element with a list, how should the function that map uses look like? I tried `func :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)` but that doesn't work. How should map even use the first argument `a`?

Comment: `fmap ((,) 1) ["abc", "def", "ghi"] => [(1,"abc"),(1,"def"),(1,"ghi")]`

Comment: Thank you both for your help.